# Why when I run Django server it fails?

Tags: python, django

**Bottom line: when I run 'python manage.py runserver 8000' I get an exception.**

**Steps that I did:**

1. This is a newly installed Windows 10, so I have installed Python3 and added all parameters to Path
2. Run '`pip install Django`' and this is what I got:
   [image]
3. Then I wanted to run Django server and run 'python manage.py runserver 8000'. Instead of running the server, here is what I got:

[image]

I know I have missed something, but can't figure out what. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Firstly, please don't post screenshots of text. Secondly, the error seems quite clear: you're using a module called "paypal" in your own Django code somewhere, but you haven't installed it.

Comment: Please _read_ the error messages Python provides you with. They are _very, very clear_, don't be afraid of them, you won't be able to debug your programs otherwise!

Comment: Thank you @DanielRoseman! (1)How should I post here code that I get? (I am a newbie so not sure what is the correct way). (2) PayPal - I will check thanks!

Comment: It's text, so please post it as actual text. You can use a code block (a 4-space indent) to format code and error messages.

Comment: Indeed, I am using in settings.py: INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'paypal.standard.ipn' ...   
) in this link: http://django-paypal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/standard/ipn.html  it is written just to add: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #...
    'paypal.standard.ipn',
    #...
] and that what I did. What am I missing here...?

Comment: This whole folder tree was taken from my old computer (and it worked fine). So I guess I just havent installed some package, but don;t understand which...

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS` tells Django what apps you have installed that Django should load. It doesn't actually install anything, for that you need to do `pip install django-paypal`.

Comment: @knbk Thank you very very much! That worked. How can I mark your answer as the "correct" answer so that you get the credits?

Comment: @Greg I've posted it in an actual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSTALLED_APPS` is a list of apps that Django should load. You still have to install the app yourself, in this case:

```
pip install django-paypal
```